# Copy security permissions of one file to another

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, acl

I would like to replicate the permissions of a file to another.
I do not want to copy the data, only the permissions.

For example, I created a **new file** and want it to have the same permissions as another file that already existed.

Comment: Same permissions as another file, but different than the directory they are in?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it in a few steps with [icacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) and a text editor.

First you must save the permissions of the original file

```
icacls C:\test\file1.bin /save perms.txt
```

you will need to edit the `perms.txt` file you just created in whatever folder you ran `icacls` in. The file should look something like this:

```
file1.bin
D:AI(A;;0x1301bf;;;BU)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)
```

You can ignore all the stuff on the 2nd row, all we care about is the first row. Change the `file1.bin` to your new filename `file2.bin` and save the file.

Now you just need to restore the file permissions on the 2nd file, note that we did not include the filename this time. (If you get an error that says "*Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.*" run the program again in an elevated command prompt.)

```
icacls C:\test\ /restore perms.txt
```

Comment: maybe put these into a script to somewhat automate the task?

Comment: It could be done, but I can't think off of the top of my head how to do step 2 easyly. Anyway if I was going to script it, I would just do the entire thing in Powershell using `File.GetAccessControl()` and `File.SetAccessControl()`

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way, by far, is to use PowerShell and run:

```
Get-Acl .\file1 | Set-Acl .\file2
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it in a batch (copy security pemissions from a subfolder or all folders of one drive to the same folder/file stricture on another drive), create a, say, `cpdacls.bat` file with this content:

```
@echo off
for /r %1 %%f in (.) do call :icacls_one %%f %2

goto :eof

:icacls_one

icacls %1\*.* /save %TEMP%\perms.txt
icacls %2.%~pnx1 /restore %TEMP%\perms.txt
del /q %TEMP%\perms.txt
```

And then run it like `cpdacls.bat e:\ f:\`.

Note that the folder structure in the destination folder must be the same as folder structure in the source folder, *taken from its root*, not depending on what subfolder you have specified as a source folder.